# What can I do to get the return value from a %def?

Tags: mako

How do I get the return value from a %def?

makoT1.py:

```
import mako
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
print "Hi world.",
mytemplate = Template(filename='makoT1.mako')
print mytemplate.render(),
```

makoT1.mako

```
<%
index = 0
%>
<%def name="a_def(counter)"> Pre: ${counter} <% counter += 1 %> Post: ${counter} <% return counter %> </%def>
index: ${index}
${a_def(index)}
index: ${index}
```

dalem@QnD:~$ python makoT1.py

```
Hi world. 

index: 0
 Pre: 0  Post: 1 1
index: 0
```

Notice that the second "index," above is still 0? That's what I'm trying to fix. I'd like it to increment.

Perhaps something like this for makoT1.mako:

```
<%
index = 0
%>
<%def name="a_def(counter)">
Pre: ${counter} 
<% counter += 1 %> 
Post: ${counter} 
<% return counter %> 
</%def>
index: ${index}
<% index = ${a_def(index)} %>
index: ${index}
```

But that gets me this error:

```
dalem@QnD:~$ python makoT1.py
Hi world.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makoT1.py", line 5, in <module>
    mytemplate = Template(filename='makoT1.mako')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 291, in __init__
    module = self._compile_from_file(path, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 368, in _compile_from_file
    filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 615, in _compile_text
    generate_magic_comment=template.disable_unicode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 597, in _compile
    node = lexer.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/lexer.py", line 241, in parse
    if self.match_python_block():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/lexer.py", line 376, in match_python_block
    match.group(1)=='!', lineno=line, pos=pos)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/lexer.py", line 131, in append_node
    node = nodecls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/parsetree.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.code = ast.PythonCode(text, **self.exception_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/ast.py", line 37, in __init__
    expr = pyparser.parse(code.lstrip(), "exec", **exception_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/pyparser.py", line 60, in parse
    ), **exception_kwargs)
mako.exceptions.SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) (u'index = ${a_def(index)} \n') in file 'makoT1.mako' at line: 11 char: 1
```

It seems odd to me that line 11 would get the SyntaxError when this works fine for line 11:

```
<% index = 0 %>
```

Shouldn't ${a_def(index)} return the integer from a_def(counter)?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<% index = a_def(index) %>
```

don't use

```
<% index = ${a_def(index)} %>
```

or

```
<% index = ${capture(a_def(index))} %>
```